# crouton - ERROR: unknown command: shell

Tags: chroot, chrome-book, chrome-os

I'm using `ASUS Chromebook Flip` with `Google Chrome OS` `53.0.2773.3.dev` and I'm trying `Usage` step from [Chromium OS Universal Chroot Environment](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton#usage):

> (Ctrl+Alt+T, type shell and hit enter)

I pressed `Ctrl+Alt+T` and new tab opened with following screen:

```
Welcome to crosh, the Chrome OS developer shell.

If you got here by mistake, don't panic!  Just close this tab and carry on.

Type 'help' for a list of commands.

crosh> shell
ERROR: unknown command: shell

crosh>
```

yet, `shell` returning `unknown command`.

How does one deal with this? (i.e. get `shell` command to be *known*)

Comment: Are you ... "just here to use crouton"? quoting: Download it, pop open a shell (Ctrl+Alt+T, type shell and hit enter), and run sh ~/Downloads/crouton to see the help text. See the "examples" section for some usage examples."

Comment: @JeffSchaller per my output, i'm failing on executing `shell` part.

Comment: It appeared from your quoted text that you had already successfully typed 'shell' and hit enter

Comment: @JeffSchaller negative, when I press `Ctrl+Alt+T` a new tab appeared, yet `shell` returns `unknown command`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your Chromebook into *developer mode* before the `shell` command will work.  This is a pre-requisite to installing `crouton` and is documented on the first line of the prereq section of the guide you are following.

How you do that will depend on your specific device; there are lots of guides out there.